# My Antlr4 grammar compiles, but the pgn files parsing is awful

Tags: grammar, antlr4, chess

I made my own grammar in order to parse chess PGN files, it compiles fine (with antlr4 command) but I can't manage to parse pgn files with it.

Pgn.g4 (antlr4 grammar, available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qo93yx0ifu2vsce/Pgn.g4))

```
grammar Pgn;

file:       game (NEWLINE+ game)*;
game:       (tag+ NEWLINE+)? notation;

tag:        '['TAG_TYPE TAG_VALUE']';
notation: move+ END_RESULT?;
move:   MOVE_NUMBER\. MOVE_DESC MOVE_DESC                   #CompleteMove
        |   MOVE_NUMBER'.' MOVE_DESC                        #OnlyWhiteMove
        |   MOVE_NUMBER'...' MOVE_DESC                      #OnlyBlackMove
        |   MOVE_NUMBER\. MOVE_DESC MOVE_DESC '(' move+ ')' #CompleteMoveWithVariant
        |   MOVE_NUMBER'.' MOVE_DESC                        #OnlyWhiteMoveWithVariant
        |   MOVE_NUMBER'...' MOVE_DESC                      #OnlyBlackMoveWithVariant
        ;

END_RESULT: '1-0'
            | '0-1'
            | '1/2-1/2'
            | '*'
            ;

TAG_TYPE:   LETTER+;
TAG_VALUE:  '"'[:print:]*'"';

MOVE_NUMBER: DIGIT+;
MOVE_DESC: [:print:];   

NEWLINE:    '\r'? '\n';
SPACES:     [ \t]+ -> skip;

fragment LETTER: [a-zA-Z];
fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
```

My test file ([Launcher.java](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k6xqqln94mtmch6/Launcher.java)) :

```
package com.gmail.bernabe.laurent.j2se.parsing_pgn_test;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;

import com.gmail.bernabe.laurent.j2se.parsing_pgn_test.pgn.PgnLexer;
import com.gmail.bernabe.laurent.j2se.parsing_pgn_test.pgn.PgnParser;

public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                "Portable Game Notation (*.pgn)", new String[]{"pgn"}));

        if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            ANTLRInputStream inStream = new ANTLRInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(fileChooser.getSelectedFile())
            );
            PgnLexer lexer = new PgnLexer(inStream);
            CommonTokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
            PgnParser parser = new PgnParser(tokenStream);

            ParseTree tree = parser.file();
            System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));
        }
   }
}
```

I tested with two samples pgn (generated with chessX program), but I made 4 for the sake of completeness : with [DebutUltraSimple.pgn](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ihe1p8dkz8o964/DebutUltraSimple.pgn) and with [FinaleUltraSimple.pgn](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j4p1v38z73khutk/FinaleUltrasimple.pgn) (remainings test pgn are [Scandinave.pgn](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ul0y7euqvpiok9q/Scandinave.pgn) and [test.pgn](https://www.dropbox.com/s/izam8mv65448j3j/test.pgn)).

The error output given by DebutUltraSimple.pgn :

```
line 1:7 token recognition error at: '"?'
line 1:9 token recognition error at: '"]'
line 1:11 mismatched input '\n' expecting TAG_VALUE
line 2:0 extraneous input '[' expecting {MOVE_NUMBER, NEWLINE}
line 2:6 token recognition error at: '"?'
line 2:8 token recognition error at: '"]'
line 3:0 extraneous input '[' expecting {MOVE_NUMBER, NEWLINE}
line 3:6 token recognition error at: '"?'
line 3:8 token recognition error at: '?'
line 3:9 token recognition error at: '?'
line 3:10 token recognition error at: '?'
line 3:12 token recognition error at: '?'
line 3:13 token recognition error at: '?'
line 3:15 token recognition error at: '?'
line 3:16 token recognition error at: '?'
line 3:17 token recognition error at: '"]'
line 4:0 extraneous input '[' expecting {MOVE_NUMBER, NEWLINE}
line 4:7 token recognition error at: '"?'
line 4:9 token recognition error at: '"]'
line 5:0 extraneous input '[' expecting {MOVE_NUMBER, NEWLINE}
line 5:7 token recognition error at: '"?'
line 5:9 token recognition error at: '"]'
line 6:0 extraneous input '[' expecting {MOVE_NUMBER, NEWLINE}
line 6:7 token recognition error at: '"?'
line 6:9 token recognition error at: '"]'
line 7:0 extraneous input '[' expecting {MOVE_NUMBER, NEWLINE}
line 7:8 token recognition error at: '"*'
line 7:10 token recognition error at: '"]'
line 8:0 extraneous input '[' expecting {MOVE_NUMBER, NEWLINE}
line 8:5 token recognition error at: '"C'
line 8:9 token recognition error at: '"]'
line 10:3 no viable alternative at input '1.e'
(file (game (tag [ Event) \n [ Site \n [ Date . . \n [ Round \n [ White \n [ Black \n [ Result \n [ ECO (notation move (move 40))) \n \n (game (notation move (move 1 . e) move (move 4 e) move (move 5) (move 2 . Nf) move (move 3 Nc) move (move 6) *)))
```

And the error output given by FinaleUltraSimple.pgn :

```
line 1:7 token recognition error at: '"tra'
line 1:16 token recognition error at: '"]'
line 1:11 mismatched input 'ining' expecting TAG_VALUE
line 2:0 extraneous input '[' expecting {MOVE_NUMBER, NEWLINE}
line 2:6 token recognition error at: '"?'
line 2:8 token recognition error at: '"]'
line 3:0 extraneous input '[' expecting {MOVE_NUMBER, NEWLINE}
line 3:6 token recognition error at: '"?'
line 3:8 token recognition error at: '?'
line 3:9 token recognition error at: '?'
line 3:10 token recognition error at: '?'
line 3:12 token recognition error at: '?'
line 3:13 token recognition error at: '?'
line 3:15 token recognition error at: '?'
line 3:16 token recognition error at: '?'
line 3:17 token recognition error at: '"]'
line 4:0 extraneous input '[' expecting {MOVE_NUMBER, NEWLINE}
line 4:7 token recognition error at: '"?'
line 4:9 token recognition error at: '"]'
line 5:0 extraneous input '[' expecting {MOVE_NUMBER, NEWLINE}
line 5:7 token recognition error at: '"w'
line 5:13 token recognition error at: '_'
line 5:21 token recognition error at: '"]'
line 6:0 extraneous input '[' expecting {MOVE_NUMBER, NEWLINE}
line 6:7 token recognition error at: '"b'
line 6:13 token recognition error at: '_'
line 6:21 token recognition error at: '"]'
line 7:0 extraneous input '[' expecting {MOVE_NUMBER, NEWLINE}
line 7:8 token recognition error at: '"1'
line 7:10 token recognition error at: '/'
line 7:12 token recognition error at: '-'
line 7:14 token recognition error at: '/'
line 7:16 token recognition error at: '"]'
line 8:5 token recognition error at: '"4'
line 8:7 mismatched input 'k' expecting TAG_VALUE
line 8:9 token recognition error at: '/'
line 8:11 token recognition error at: '/'
line 8:16 token recognition error at: '/'
line 8:18 token recognition error at: '/'
line 8:20 token recognition error at: '/'
line 8:22 token recognition error at: '/'
line 8:24 token recognition error at: '/'
line 8:29 token recognition error at: '-'
line 8:31 token recognition error at: '-'
line 8:36 token recognition error at: '"]'    
line 9:0 extraneous input '[' expecting {MOVE_NUMBER, NEWLINE}
line 9:7 token recognition error at: '"1'
line 9:9 token recognition error at: '"]'
line 11:5 no viable alternative at input '1...Kf'
line 11:35 token recognition error at: '='
(file (game (tag [ Event ining) \n [ Site \n [ Date . . \n [ Round \n [ White hite trainer \n [ Black lack trainer \n [ Result (notation move (move 2) (move 1) (move 2))) \n (game (tag [ FEN k 3 8 4 KP 2 8 8 8 8 8 b 0 1) \n [ Setup \n \n (notation move (move 1 ... Kf) move (move 8) (move 2 . f) move (move 7 Kg) move (move 7) (move 3 . Ke) move (move 7 Kg) move (move 6) (move 4 . f) move (move 8 Q) 1/2-1/2)))
```

Some links on the generated source code :

[Pgn.tokens](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qw6skjdao62whuo/Pgn.tokens)

[PgnBaseListener.java](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5vrgfpqe32b1o6p/PgnBaseListener.java)

[PgnLexer.java](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f7cx86mdutk4zgj/PgnLexer.java)

[PgnLexer.tokens](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rtiknixmn48kyex/PgnLexer.tokens)

[PgnListener.java](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o4wga8wv0n0m3qc/PgnListener.java)

[PgnParser.java](https://www.dropbox.com/s/icxjyyy888wqtvj/PgnParser.java)

The [eclipse project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zjzfx3wr9ad9u9n/ParsingPgnTest.zip) (zipped) I used in order to test.

Helps and advices will be well appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is you found this construction "[:print:]"?
you could use like this:

```
TAG_VALUE:  '"' (~[\"])* '"';
```

And you of course must change it also for token MOVE_DESC.

And you have some problems in here, because your "tag" ends with "NEWLINE", but there are more than 1 "tag" before "notation" in pgn files:

```
game:       (tag+ NEWLINE+)? notation;
tag:        '['TAG_TYPE TAG_VALUE']';
```

And better to use ANTRLWorks2 for debugging your grammar files.

Comment: [:print:] is used in Standard Regex ... but not in Antlr4. Thanks. And thank you also for your suggestion about ANTLRWorks2 debugger. I'll have a look at it :)